# Can a water damaged motherboard or power supply ruin a functional CPU?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, desktop-computer, post, water-damage

I found half of a desktop on the side of the road the other day. It included a 430 watt power supply, DVD r/writer, ASRock B250M-HDV motherboard, Pentium g4560 CPU, as well as a case with both side panels missing. This open case left part of the motherboard exposed to the elements on both sides.

The system appeared to have been left out overnight, with dew in the grass leaving traces of water on the case and motherboard. However, the CPU remained dry, as it was protected by the socket on one side and the stock cooler on the other.

Could powering a possibly water damaged motherboard, or a water damaged power supply destroy a CPU? Is there a way to check motherboard functionality or power supply functionality without the necessity of a CPU for a POST?

Comment: Of course, damaged m/b can kill CPU. Assume that m/b core power source is damaged and its output voltage is too high... And no way to test m/b without CPU - because just CPU executes all POST tests.

Comment: Assuming the system was functional before being put to the road - simply let it dry thoroughly and power up. Water does not damage electronics. Electricity flowing through the water does. If there was no power on the system when it was wet then it will function as normal once it is dry. It’s not a universal statement, but for the most part is true.

Comment: You could probably bench test PSU by jumpering 2 of the connections together - green and black iirc. Also dew is the best case -pure water dosen't conduct

Comment: *Water does not damage electronics.* But the salts and another substances contained in dirty water - did... The dew is dirty - it contains dust particles (especially near the road) and substances dissolved/extracted from this dust.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Practically speaking, you can probably, very carefully, test components individually other than the CPU.

There are a few things worth remembering. Unlike what the comments say, water doesn't actually conduct electricity - it's the *impurities* in water that conduct the current, and dew is roughly as pure as it gets. As long as the electrical components are completely dry, and there are no water stains, you *should* for most part be safe.

You can probably test the parts in isolation. The thing I find fishy here is that it's a relatively recent PC according to your decription, even if it is at the lower end of the spectrum. I'd guess, as a former owner of a dumpster dived PC, that either *something* has failed, or it's stolen property that they couldn't sell off.

You can do a quick bench test to see if the magic smoke escaped from a PSU by shorting out the green and black (IIRC - *do* check before actually doing anything) cables on a PSU and see if the fan powers up. I'd still test the motherboard and PC with a *known good* power supply

The manual doesn't indicate status LEDs, so you'll want a PC speaker to tell what's wrong.

That's to say, it's entirely plausible that there's no damage, or any damage is from *before* the system was thrown out. That said, there are a few things that don't add up, such as the recent vintage of the PC.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there isn't a way to test a motherboard in the POST without a CPU. The CPU I believe is one of the first things that powers on in POST besides an internal voltage detector to make sure voltage is at a certain level before initializing. However, you can easily test the CPU by installing it into another motherboard that supports it.

By the way... Pentium??? Wow....

But anyway, you can try to dry out the motherboard manually. A fan, cool dry or warm dry air even better. Or you can get some 99& isopropanol alcohol and a Q-tip and go to town on dabbing wet places with the Q-tip soaked with the alcohol. This helps evaporate the moisture.

To answer your question: There is a small possibility that powering up a damaged motherboard can damage a CPU, due to erratic electrical signals from severed connections in the circuitry.

Comment: "Could powering a possibly water damaged motherboard, or a water damaged power supply destroy a CPU?"

Comment: Pentium as a brand is still alive and the G4560 is a modern chip (released 2017).

Comment: Many budget PCs in developing countries actually do still ship with (modern) Pentium processors

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that. Cool. Good to see the Pentium still alive.

Comment: @KALI99 Celeron is still around too as a brand/  In both cases, they're respectively one and two steps below a Core i3 in terms of Intel's performance targets.  Pentiums aren't too horrible if you just need a bit of processing power, but the modern Celeron parts are generally near useless for anything but IoT type devices because they take far too long to do anything, even when using Linux or BSD.

Comment: Oh I understand what you mean Austin Hemmelgarn. In this laptop I'm using right now, an HP 2000-299wm running a dual-boot Windows 7 and Debian 9, I used to have a Celeron T3500 at about 2.1 GHz. Back when I got this on ebay, I thought GHz was everything. I soon figured out that GHz was in fact NOT everything. I did research and bought the best CPU my motherboard can handle, a Core 2 Duo T9900 3.05 Ghz. And still to this day it seems my computer is not as fast as every other laptop out there. Celeron was in fact a VERY slow CPU. However, when I installed Debian, my computer ran lightning quick.